# iTunes Connect file upload size issue

Tags: app-store-connect, filesize

I am trying to upload txt file(4,073 bytes) through iTunes Connect to manage content of one of my apps. It didn't allow me to upload and said file size is more than 4000 Characters. Then, I removed couple of characters from the file manually and uploaded the txt file (4,045 bytes) and it was accepted by iTunes Connect.

Not sure how do I restrict/determine the size of the txt file? Since I have an automated tool which basically generates the file with 4000 bytes/characters limit, which obviously ignored by iTunes connect.

Comment: I *think* you're talking about the application description field, right?  I vaguely remember there being a bit of play in terms of one being able to add a few more characters beyond the official text length limit... but why not simply try to keep whatever txt file you are uploading at or under 4000 bytes?  Is it that hard for you?

Comment: yes, i am talking about app description field. I can keep character count below 4000. But, i want to setup a limit where my editors(non-techies) can adjust the count with the limit. But, this strange behavior of iTunes connects is bit annoying. -Removed 28 Characters, accepted by Apple iTC
file size was 4,061 bytes - Now 4,036 bytes

-Removed 31 Characters, accepted by Apple iTC
File size was 4,073 bytes - Now 4,046 bytes

-Removed 29 Characters, accepted by Apple iTC
file size Was 4,060 bytes - Now 4,034 bytes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best option would be to set the limit to be 4,000 characters and just stick with that.

You never know when Apple will tighten up on the iTunesConnect application description field's (possibly temporary) flexibility.